# Como capturar dados binários de um contexto WebGL?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webgl

Eu criei dois clientes HTML que se comunicam por meio de um servidor websocket.
Um dos clientes desenha um modelo 3D em um canvas utilizando a biblioteca Three.js e depois envia o arquivo binário do contexto WebGL do canvas para o outro cliente pelo websocket. Praticamente uma stream de canvas entre vários clientes.

[A base do código de renderização 3D](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_effects_peppersghost.html)

O problema é que a biblioteca do WebGL é bastante ineficiente, a ponto que a única forma que consegui fazer enviar os dados binários foi utilizando o método `gl.readPixels()` que é MUITO lento (aproximadamente uns 3 segundos). Sendo que eu preciso que fique da forma mais fluida possivel.

Segue abaixo a forma que capturo o contexto webGL e envio pelo websocket.

```
function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    render();

    var ctx = renderer.getContext();        

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(1280 * 720 * 4);

    ctx.readPixels(0,0,1280, 720, ctx.RGBA, ctx.UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteArray);

    socket.send(byteArray.buffer);

}
```

Comment: Você quer enviar uma imagem 1280x720 por um socket a cada quadro de animação?! Supondo 24 frames por segundo, você precisaria de uma conexão de rede de 88 megabytes por segundo no mínimo... Sobre o `readPixels`, de fato é uma operação relativamente lenta, mas 3 segundos é demais! (ouço falar de 10ms ou algo assim) Que browser e sistema operacional você está usando? Tem certeza que o gargalo é o `readPixels`, e não alguma outra operação no seu código?

Comment: Você pode enviada instruções utilizando JSON para o outro cliente e reconstruir um modelo 3D reproduzir instrucoes aqui.